# Draft workflow item page editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

In sitecore 7.2 which is an upgraded site from sitecore 6.5, when I create a new item which will be in the draft workflow state and click publish--> Page Editor the user will be redirected to home item, but when the item is on the final workflow the page editor will work fine.

There is a lot of code customization in the solution, Not sure if it is a sitecore issue or a custom code cause this?.

Comment: Pretty broad question. Are  you accessing the CMS on the host name that the site is supposed to run on?   Is ContentEditing enabled for the site?  Are there custom redirect handlers or 404 handlers that might be interfering?

Comment: What are the Workflow Actions on the draft state? Is there anything custom there

Comment: Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: There is no custom code on the workflow I defined new workflow and still the same result, And there are no errors in the log file, 

If I update the draft and select the Final checkbox then the item in the draft state will be editable in page editor.

Comment: the "
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.FilterItem.DisableApprovedVersionFiltering, Sitecore.Kernel"/> " was missing in web.config, adding this processor solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user have access to the 'approval' state? It is possible your permissions are set up such that the user no longer has read access once the item moves to the approval state, so you get redirected to the home page.

@Mohammed Syam discovered that this was due to the following configuration issue:

> the "<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.FilterItem.DisableApprovedVersionFiltering, Sitecore.Kernel"/> " was missing in web.config, adding this processor solve this issue

Comment: Yes The user has permission

Comment: The user that I use is administrator

Comment: the " <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.FilterItem.DisableApprovedVersionFiltering, Sitecore.Kernel"/> " was missing in web.config, adding this processor solve this issue

Comment: You should add that as an answer so you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: Jay S : I could't add an answer I think because the question is closed.

Comment: I've included your solution into my answer since I could edit it.